# Springboot/Keycloak unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am creating AuthzClient to manually validate token, but getting below TLS verification error, i added my CA certificate to the cacerts of my JDK (which is version 17) and still getting same error, tried to add truststore with AuthzClient Configuration but still didn't work, how to disable SSL verification in Springboot or properly configure it, without Rest Templates.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.controllers.TelephonyWebsocketHandler]: Factory method 'telephonyWebsocketHandler' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not obtain configuration from server [https://atcom-cc/auth/realms/atcom/.well-known/uma2-configuration].
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not obtain configuration from server [https://atcom-cc/auth/realms/atcom/.well-known/uma2-configuration].
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:266) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.create(AuthzClient.java:94) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.controllers.TelephonyWebsocketHandler.<init>(TelephonyWebsocketHandler.java:74) ~[main/:na]
        at com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.config.WebsocketsConfiguration.telephonyWebsocketHandler(WebsocketsConfiguration.java:46) ~[main/:na]
        at com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.config.WebsocketsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee0ba706.CGLIB$telephonyWebsocketHandler$3(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.config.WebsocketsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee0ba706$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d4491dc8.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at com.atcom.cc.aes.connector.config.WebsocketsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee0ba706.telephonyWebsocketHandler(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing http method [GET]. Response : null
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:106) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:50) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:264) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
        at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:84) ~[keycloak-authz-client-18.0.0.jar:18.0.0]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341) ~[na:na]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I see you're using springboot, so do you have some keycloak configs on your .properties/.yml config file? Sometimes there are issues with the property "auth-server-url" which is not set correctly

Comment: @Ruber, yes i am using springboot and i do have config in the .properties file, keycloak is working fine and i am able to authenticate all my REST services, but i have one requirement where i will receive the token over websocket as String, and i want to get the token's user details, I'm calling Keycloak webservice in code with RestTemplate but a better approach is if i could use the AuthzClient since it is already there, but i think it is not exposed as a Bean thus i cannot pass it in constructor or Autowire it, so i am creating a AuthzClient but getting the above TLS error